# What type can I use to represent the __Renderings field in a Glass model?

Tags: c#, sitecore, glass-mapper

I would like to access the Sitecore built in "__Renderings" field as a property of a Glass model. What type can I use to do this ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the renderings field you should do something like this:

```
[SitecoreField(FieldName="__Renderings")]
public virtual string Renderings {get;set;}
```

If you want to handle the object as something else you will need to implement a custom data handler. You can find the tutorial on how to do this [here](http://glass.lu/docs/tutorial/sitecore/tutorial19/tutorial19.html). After that you will just need to  set the datatype of the field to something like:

```
[SitecoreField(FieldName="__Renderings")]
public virtual IEnumerable<Rendering> Renderings {get;set;}
```

Comment: When implementing you custom data handler look at the item.Visualization property and then the Sitecore.Data.Items.ItemVisualization class.